# Chrome Extension API - Trigger File Upload Dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to trigger a file upload dialog from my content script.

When I type the following in the page console directly, it works and shows the input dialog box.

```
document.getElementById("upload").click();
```

But if I do the same in my content.js script, it doesn't.

I also tried to inject a script in the page and then trigger it;

```
injectScript('events.js');

function injectScript(filename) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  // TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
  script.src = chrome.extension.getURL(filename);
  script.onload = function() {
      this.remove();
  };
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
}

//in document ready
var event = document.createEvent('customEvent');
event.initCustomEvent('triggerUpload', true, true, {});
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

And then in events.js:

```
document.addEventListener('triggerUpload', function (e) {
    console.log("inside"); //yes, my event triggered successfully

    var el = document.getElementById("upload");

    el.click();

    //other things tried..
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click", false, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);

    var event = new Event('click');
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

However, nothing works.

Is this not possible?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events - From what i can see here your `'customEvent'` needs to be changed to `'Event'` or `'triggerUpload'`

Comment: @Deckerz my event is triggered so that should not be the issue (I did change it per your recommendations as initCustomEvent is deprecated, but it doesn't change the outcome).

Comment: i would have a look at the bottom most example in the link i sent. It seems pretty useful for what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @Deckerz I did, I receive an alert with "not cancelled" when I add that code in my event listener (with correct element, of course). But no file dialog triggered.

Comment: can we see the html?